# How to remove sticky header when scrolling to the 3rd paragraph for example ? Or a specific item in the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to remove sticky header when scrolling to the 3rd paragraph for example ? Or a specific item in the page ? this is the code below.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you want to remove the sticky header after p5 ,you can do it like this

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            const p5 = document.getElementById('p5')
            const nav = document.querySelector('.nav')
            var top = p5.getBoundingClientRect().top
            if (top < 126 || top >270 ) {
                nav.style.position = 'relative'
            } else {
                nav.style.position = 'sticky'
            }
        })
```

```css
.nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    p {
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }
    
    .p5 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #p3 {
        background-color: greenyellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        hi nav bar
    </div>
    <div class="p">
        <p id="p1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p4">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p class='p5' id="p5">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p7">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p8">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p9">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p10">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p11">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
        <p id="p13">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At voluptates doloremque, dolores,<br>pariatur officia debitis quos, praesentium molestiae vel mollitia eos illo ipsa fugit! Quo soluta a vero dicta amet?

        </p>
    </div>
```

you can change the top value to get perfect time based on your website

```
if (top < 126)
```

Comment: How can I make it start further down the page though ? For example start at paragraph 3 and stop at paragraph 5 ? cause it starts too at the top of the page ...

Comment: i edited the snippest to start from p3 and end at p5 you just need to edit  the top value